# Predicting a score for a test?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can anyone explain what goes in these matrices?

Answer (score 1):

Each student's score list gives you one equation. The unknowns are $c,m,n$.  The first equation is $76=c+70m+89n$  Can you write the other two equations?  Then put them into the form $A\vec x = \vec b$?  That will give you what goes into the boxes.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find constants $c,m,n$ such that the relation
$$f=c+mx+ny$$
is satisfied by the given data.  That is, you want
$$76=c+70m+89n$$
and two other equations.  In matrix form,
$$\pmatrix{1&70&89\cr ?&?&?\cr ?&?&?\cr}\pmatrix{c\cr m\cr n\cr}=\pmatrix{76\cr?\cr?\cr}\ .$$
See if you can fill in the rest.